# Is there a way to convert string to json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert list of string into json object.
My string is : personName + rank.
This is string is arranged as per the person's rank.
PS: the backend code is in solidity
My code so far is as follows:

```
    var ranks = new Array(5);
    PersonNames = Object.keys(names);
    ranks = contractInstance.dashboard.call(PersonNames);// function in solidity

    var finalList = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++){
      var winList = web3.toAscii(ranks[j]);
      var winCount = contractInstance.RanksFor.call(ranks[j]).toString();
      var person = {};
        person["name"] = winList[j];
        console.log(winList[j]);
        person["ranks"] = winCount[j];
      finalList.push(person);
    }
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(finalList);
```

Please let me know if I am making use of the correct syntax.
I am learning how to implement javascript. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object duplicate. Additionally why aren't you just building a JSON object using the function. Instead of turning it to and from a json object?

Comment: Question is Confusing. Are you creating a JSON String? Your code is creating a JSON String. What is the objective?

Comment: My output is coming undefined

Comment: My winList holds name of people who received highest rank. and wincount holds their rank number. My final objective is to generate table which contains person's name and his/her rank.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the provided method is the best way...

Example 1:

```
var json = JSON.parse('{ "hello":"world" }');
```

Example 2:

```
var json = '{"hello":"world"}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);
```